# Understanding Kafka Horizontally Scaling: When do I need a new Broker?

Tags: apache-kafka

When we want to horizontally scale a kafka cluster, we can do so by adding more kafka brokers. I I have been trying to understand, how does one decide "now is the time to add a broker to a kafka cluster"?

For sake of simplicity assuming that failover is not a requirement.

Are there:

- any best practices in choosing the number of kafka brokers?
- metrics that should be monitored? (number of partitions / consumers / producers / bytes trasnferred?)
- any resources, we could use to monitor the health of the kafka brokers?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from host machine storage, CPU, Memory and Networking,  since Kafka brokers runs on JVM, all the important stats like heap memory, threads are important to
monitor and should be considered when scaling needs arises. From perspective of messaging functionality since topics are implemented as partitions
or commit ahead logs which are appended serially it's important to monitor the disk writes as well. Similarly since Kafka stores the messages persistently
for a predefined period - the storage size for each partition and overall size is also important.

You can use performance scripts provided by Kafka ([here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh) and [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh)) and experiment with different setting like [here](https://gist.github.com/jkreps/c7ddb4041ef62a900e6c) to try out different configurations, monitor your cluster during the performance run and then decide right scaling for your use case.

Comment: Thanks Shailedra for your answer it already helps quite a bit, do you have any pointers on how one could estimate how many kafka brokers one would need?